# ORA-01861 date column issue in stored procedure

Tags: python, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a below query in oracle stored procedure which is causing the issue.

```
Select * 
from my_table 
where TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(billing_date,'DD-MON-YY',NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'),'YYYY-MM-DD') ='2018-06-1';
```

I am getting ORA-01861:literal does not match format string.

My billing_date is having date like 01-JUN-18 and it's a date type column

I am executing this stored procedure using cx_Oracle in Python.

Comment: This is a long process, What type of outputs are you getting in the stored procedure and what kind of inputs are you giving in.

- Why I am asking is because this  requires type definitions before hand.

Comment: `billing_date` isn't a `varchar` (or `varchar2` or any string type), isn't it? If it is fix the schema and use the right type like `date` for it.

Comment: Why do you convert a STRING into a DATE and then again into a STRING? Apart from that, the format is wrong. Use `DD-MON-RR` and `2018-06-01` or - much better - use `DATE` data type for `billing_date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading your code, it appears that `billing_date` column's datatype is `varchar2`. If so, this might help:

```
SQL> with my_table (id, billing_date) as
  2    (select 1, '20-jan-20' from dual union all
  3     select 2, '16-jun-19' from dual union all
  4     select 3, '01-jun-18' from dual
  5    )
  6  select *
  7  from my_table
  8  where billing_date = to_char(date '2018-06-01', 'dd-mon-yy', 'nls_date_language = english');

        ID BILLING_D
---------- ---------
         3 01-jun-18

SQL>
```

---

If, on the other hand, `billing_date` is `date`, then it gets simpler:

```
SQL> with my_table (id, billing_date) as
  2    (select 1, date '2020-01-20' from dual union all
  3     select 2, date '2019-06-16' from dual union all
  4     select 3, date '2018-06-01' from dual
  5    )
  6  select *
  7  from my_table
  8  where billing_date = date '2018-06-01';

        ID BILLING_
---------- --------
         3 01.06.18

SQL>
```

Comment: Saying that "My billing_date is having date like 01-JUN-18 and it's a date type column", well - that's wrong. You *see* it like that, but it is stored in Oracle's internal format, 7 bytes. It means that my second suggestion should work properly.

Comment: According to the question the date strings in `billing_date` seems to use 2-digit years. in this case the first query should not work.

Comment: Right, @Wernfried, thank you. However, that "mistake" doesn't change much, it is just about year format mask in line #8 (YY instead of YYYY). Anyway, as data is stored as DATE, that really doesn't change anything in the final outcome.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use dates as following:

```
Select * from my_table where billing_date = date'2018-06-01';
```

Considering that your `billing_date` is of date type column.

Cheers!!